# Kendo Grid doesn't work after an error

Tags: kendo-grid

Ours is a SPA which uses Kendo Grid with server-side sorting, paging and filtering. Whenever we get an exception during sorting, paging or filtering at the server, the grid just freezes and nothing works. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code...  does the server return the error to the client?

Comment: Yes, a 500 internal server error with some error text.

Comment: Can you post the relevant client code?